# Rails bootstrap-editable-rails not displaying current text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the gem 'bootstrap-editable-rails' to in-line edit a text column.  I want the it to display the current text in the column.  But, right now it displays "Empty" instead.  If I click on it and enter new text, it successfully replaces the column value in the database - so the updating is working.

The table is called "taskup".  The text column is called "comments".

This is the code in the view file:

```
<a href="#" class="answer" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-resource="taskup"  data-name="comments" data-url="/taskups/<%= taskup.id %>" ></a>
```

And this is the coffee script:

```
  $(".answer").editable()
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost!  You're missing to set the value inside the a tag

```
<a href="#" class="answer" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-resource="taskup"  data-name="comments" data-url="/taskups/<%= taskup.id %>" >
<%= taskup.comments ? taskup.comments : ''>
</a>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I added the `<% task.comments ? task.comments : '' %>` - but, got `undefined method `comments' for #<Task:0x007fe469e5d058>`